# How to measure # of lines of code in project?

Tags: php, metrics, line-count

How can I measure number of lines of code in my PHP web development projects?

Edit: I'm interested in windows tools only

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you're using a full fledged IDE the quick and dirty way is to count the number of "\n" patterns using the search feature (assuming it supports regexes)

Comment: Lines of code is *not* the same as number of lines in the file. Especially for PHP, which often has code interspersed with markup.

Comment: Which is why I was so surprised. :)

Answer (score 28):

Check [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/), it's a source code line counter that supports many languages, I always recommend it.

It will differentiate between actual lines of code, blank lines or comments, it's very good.

In addition there are more code counters that you can check:

- [SLOCCount](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/)
- [sclc](http://www.dwheeler.com/sloccount/)
- USC's [CODECOUNT](http://sunset.usc.edu/research/CODECOUNT/)
- [loc](http://freshmeat.net/projects/loc/)
- [Ohcount](http://labs.ohloh.net/ohcount)

Comment: All of these are linux tools, do you have any windows ones?

Comment: Hey, check the download link of CLOC, http://downloads.sourceforge.net/cloc/cloc-1.06.exe?modtime=1223154209&big_mirror=0

Comment: I did download it but i got a blank DOS screen and then it disappeared?

Comment: It's a console app!, you have to run it from the command line, i.e. cloc-1.06.exe C:\myProject\folder

Comment: Thanks, i tried it but there's something wrong, it said there were only 3 PHP files in my project? that's impossible. Other than that it seems very useful :)

Answer (score 4):

[phploc](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc)

No experience if it runs on Windows, tho, but searching on the web showed some results of people getting it to work on Windows..

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a linux box, the easiest way is probably directed by this SO question:

[count (non-blank) lines-of-code in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114814/count-non-blank-lines-of-code-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS code, install this extension called [Lines of Code (LOC)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lyzerk.linecounter)

After installation, use `ctrl`+`p`, type `linecount`, and you will find below options.

[image]

`Count Workspace files` will give the output in the following format.

[image]

This works on any OS with VS Code with the above plugin installed.

Answer (score 1):

1. npm install -g cloc
2. Go to the project folder
3. Delete the node_modules and dist folder (if you have any), Because you don't need to calculate loc in dist and node_modules
4. inside the project folder
5. run this command: `cloc *`

Output will look like this :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Our [SD Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine) is a GUI for searching across large bodies of source code such as a PHP web site.  It is fast because it preindexes the source code.

As a side effect of the indexing process, it also computes metrics on the source code base, including SLOC, Comments, blank lines, Cyclomatic and Halsted complexity numbers.

And it runs on Windows.

Comment: Downvoter: what's the objection? It not only counts  *code* lines accuratly but also provides additional metrics data.