# Count number of blank lines in a file

Tags: unix, sed, grep, text-files

In [count (non-blank) lines-of-code in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114814/count-non-blank-lines-of-code-in-bash) they explain how to count the number of non-empty lines.

But is there a way to count the number of blank lines in a file? By blank line I also mean lines that have spaces in them.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Another way is:

```
grep -cvP '\S' file
```

- `-P '\S'`(perl regex) will match any line contains non-space
- `-v` select non-matching lines
- `-c` print a count of matching lines

---

If your grep doesn't support `-P` option, please use `-E '[^[:space:]]'`

Comment: This works and is also very fast when compared with other answer, so I am accepting this answer over the other one.

Comment: I also blogged about it at http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/count-the-number-of-empty-lines-in-a-file-using-grep

Comment: For easy copying for OSX users:  `grep -cvE '[^[:space:]]'`

Comment: On Mac, use `grep -cvE '\S' file`

Comment: With GNU grep `grep -cvE '\S' file` and `grep -cv '\S' file` work, too. Whether they are faster or slower than with `-P`, depends on hardware and grep version. E.g. with grep version 2.25 with Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270   @ 1.60GHz perl regex is slower, and grep version 2.16 with Intel(R) Core(TM)2 CPU          6400  @ 2.13GHz perl regex is faster.

Comment: `grep -cx '\s*' file` is also pretty fast depending on hardware and grep implementation. See my answer.

Answer (score 28):

One way using `grep`:

```
grep -c "^$" file
```

Or with whitespace:

```
grep -c "^\s*$" file
```

Comment: Thanks this works. But I am going to choose the other answer, since it  was very fast.

Comment: I can't understand why one should be faster than the other one and can't think of a material to test the difference, can you please explain or give numbers? I do think both should give the exact same efficiency. And as this answer is more straightforward, I think it's the best one. The other one use a double negation : invert match on none space character.

Comment: @AdrienHorgnies use e.g. https://www.ietf.org/download/rfc-index.txt as test file, and use `time` to measure the execution time.

Comment: @AdrienHorgnies see also my answer.

Comment: @AdrienHorgnies Implementation of grep and even hardware used may affect relative efficiency of the commands as you can see in my comment to kev's answer. Also the amount of complexity of pattern may affect it; using some options instead of writing more complex pattern may be more efficient, if the options are implemented more efficiently than interpreting of the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `awk` for this:

```
awk '!NF {sum += 1} END {print sum}' file
```

From the manual, "The variable NF is set to the total number of fields in the input record". Since the default field separator is the space, any line consisting in either nothing or some spaces will have `NF=0`.

Then, it is a matter of counting how many times this happens.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
aa dd

ddd


he      llo
$ cat -vet a # -vet to show tabs and spaces
aa dd$
    $
ddd$
   $
^I$
he^Illo$
```

Now let's' count the number of blank lines:

```
$ awk '!NF {s+=1} END {print s}' a
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne '$count++ if /^\s*$/; END { print int $count }' input.file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -v '\S' | wc -l
```

(On OSX the Perl expressions are not available, -P option)

Comment: Please elaborate a little on your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

`grep -cx '\s*' file`

or

`grep -cx '[[:space:]]*' file`

That is faster than the code in Steve's answer.

Answer (score 1):

To count how many ***useless blank lines*** your colleague has inserted in a project you can launch a one-line command like this:

```
blankLinesTotal=0; for file in $( find . -name "*.cpp" ); do blankLines=$(grep -cvE '\S' ${file}); blankLinesTotal=$[${blankLines} + ${blankLinesTotal}]; echo $file" has" ${blankLines} " empty lines."  ; done; echo "Total: "${blankLinesTotal}
```

This prints:

```
<filename0>.cpp #blankLines
....
....
<filenameN>.cpp #blankLines
Total #blankLinesTotal
```