# Why these patterns return same result?

Tags: grep

I saw this question: [count (non-blank) lines-of-code in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114814/count-non-blank-lines-of-code-in-bash/22774449)

I understand this pattern is correct.

```sh
grep -vc ^$ filename
```

Why this pattern returns same result?

```sh
grep -c '[^ ]' filename
```

What is trick in `'[^ ]'`?

Comment: `grep -c '[^ ]'` counts any line that has a non-space character. For example, `foo 123` will be counted since alphabets are not a space character. So, which one to use depends on whether a line containing only space characters should be counted or not.

Comment: Thanks for a comment. I think your comment is enough as an answer. I want to approval, can you write as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sh
$ printf 'foo 123\n  \nxyz\n\t\n' > ip.txt
$ cat -T ip.txt
foo 123
  
xyz
^I

$ grep -vc '^$' ip.txt
4
$ grep -c '[^ ]' ip.txt
3
$ grep -c '[^[:blank:]]' ip.txt
2
```

`grep -c '[^ ]'` counts any line that has a non-space character. For example, `foo 123` will be counted since alphabets are not space characters. So, which one to use depends on whether a line containing only space characters should be counted or not.